# Family History location

Tags: locating-records

I am trying to locate an American Airman (aged 27 in 1960) who was on a 3 year contract and based in Oxfordshire England between 1958 and 1960 who married in 1955 an English girl(aged 25 in 1960).  On 10 May 1960 he adopted 2 children my nephew Michael John (Mike?) born 21 August 1956 and niece Kim Marie, born 23 November 1957 and I believe returned to the USA in 1961. I believe the wife was living in Uxbridge(England) during the period. Unfortunately I am unable to obtain the surname of the couple although the Children did keep their Christian Names - I am told that the surname could be Irish name. Is there any way from immigration records whether I can get any information or via US air force. I know I am asking a big question without the surname. Can anyone help me.  Regards Susan.

Comment: Hi, Susan -- Welcome to G&FH.SE! This kind of question is not a good fit for our site  because you are asking about locating individuals who might be living --  see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  You will probably get better advice asking this question on forums that are designed to help adoptees reunite with their families.  You can edit your question using the edit link under your question if you want to re-frame your question to focus more on finding records rather than locating people.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about locating identifiable living individuals.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the specific base or squadron he was in, you might be able to find a veteran's web site.
This link has a list of bases, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Air_Force_in_the_United_Kingdom#USAF_bases_in_the_United_Kingdom